# Why does top/bottom margin set to % change when resizing the screen horizontally?

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive-design

Why does top/bottom margin set to % change when resizing the screen horizontally?

Here is an example of a layout with boxes, and I've set all of the margins to 1.45%. I do understand why the left and right margins change, but why do the top and bottom margins change when I resize the screen HORIZONTALLY? **Is there any way to implement this so that they only change when resizing screen VERTICALLY?**

https://jsfiddle.net/c60ymrfu/2/

```
.item {
  width:30%;
  margin-left:1.45%;
  margin-right:1.45%;
  margin-top: 1.45%;
  margin-bottom: 1.45%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: *margin* and *padding* in percentages are based on the `width` in CSS... that's why  this behaviour... see another interesting margin issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105138

Comment: instead of *percentages* you can use *viewport units*: https://jsfiddle.net/xqn2vybg/

Comment: From the W3C CSS spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html):
The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box’s containing block. Note that this is true for margin-top and margin-bottom as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vh here 
vh: is viewport height which will be only reacting when the height change not on width change.

```
.item {
  width:30%;
  margin-left:1.45%;
  margin-right:1.45%;
  margin-top: 1vh;
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
}
```

Read more about units here 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length